# Python idiom for dict-able classes?

Tags: python, abc

I want to do something like this:

```
class Dictable:
    def dict(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Foo(Dictable):
    def dict(self):
        return {'bar1': self.bar1, 'bar2': self.bar2}
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do this? For example, is it possible to overload the built-in conversion `dict(...)`? Note that I don't necessarily want to return all the member variables of `Foo`, I'd rather have each class decide what to return.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into overloading __getitem__ or __setitem__ so you can say foo['key']? (given foo is an instance of you class)

Comment: @JonClements The use case for me is I have some objects which all should be able to be serialized into JSON objects to be returned in a web server application. I turn them into `dict`s since the web framework handles the `dict->JSON string` part automatically.

Comment: Also they cannot just be `dict`s in the first place since they are also SQLAlchemy ORM classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Pythonic way depends on what you want to do. If your objects shouldn't be regarded as mappings in their own right, then a `dict` method is perfectly fine, but you shouldn't "overload" `dict` to handle dictables. Whether or not you need the base class depends on whether you want to do `isinstance(x, Dictable)`; note that `hasattr(x, "dict")` would serve pretty much the same purpose.

If the classes *are* conceptually mappings of keys to values, then implementing the [`Mapping`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) protocol seems appropriate. I.e., you'd implement

- `__getitem__`
- `__iter__`
- `__len__`

and inherit from `collections.Mapping` to get the other methods. Then you get `dict(Foo())` for free. Example:

```
class Foo(Mapping):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in ("bar1", "bar2"):
            raise KeyError("{} not found".format(repr(key))
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield "bar1"
        yield "bar2"

    def __len__(self):
        return 2
```

Comment: Can't see a requirement for this as we don't have a use case - but my answer would also be based on ABC's - AFAICT a dict would just do the job - if attribute access was *really* required then a `namedtuple` could be more useful as the `value` part of `key`.

Comment: The classes I am using `Dictable` for are SQLAlchemy ORM classes, so I suppose they don't do much besides map keys to values (along with some under the hood DB stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, look at [`collections.ABC`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html), which describes the Python abstract base class protocol (equivalent to interfaces in static languages).

Then, decide if you want to write your own ABC or make use of an existing one; in this case, [Mapping](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) might be what you want.

Note that although the `dict` constructor (i.e. `dict(my_object)`) is not overrideable, if it encounters an iterable object that yields a sequence of key-value pairs, it will construct a dict from that; i.e. (Python 2; for Python 3 replace `items` with `iteritems`):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return {'bar1': self.bar1, 'bar2': self.bar2}.iteritems()
```

However, if your classes are intended to behave like a `dict` you shouldn't do this as it's different from the expected behaviour of a `Mapping` instance, which is to iterate over keys, not key-value pairs.  In particular it would cause `for .. in` to behave incorrectly.

Comment: `__iter__` on a `Mapping` should generate the keys, not key-value pairs.

Comment: @larsmans good point, I was just thinking how unpythonic it was.  Will correct.

Comment: the strange thing is that I cannot find this requirement in the docs for the `Mapping` ABC, nor the glossary...

Comment: @larsmans http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__ *For mappings, it should iterate over the keys of the container*

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly overload dict() but you almost never want to!  Too many aspects of the standard library depend upon dict being available and you will break most of its functionality.  You cab probably do something like this though:

```
class Dictable:
   def dict(self):
     return self.__dict__
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are about making your class behave like a dict, which isn't actually what you asked.  If you want to express the idea, "I am a class that can be turned into a dict," I would simply define a bunch of classes and have them each implement .dict().  Python favors duck-typing (what an object can do) over what an object is.  The ABC doesn't add much.  Documentation serves the same purpose.